# oracle TO_CHAR format (decimal always required)

Tags: oracle, format, data-conversion

I need to convert my oracle NUMBER into a string with this format: 999,999

I'm trying with TO_CHAR but I'm not having the correct output.

This is the expected behavior:

```
9 ---> 9,000
9,88 --> 9,880
0 --> 0,000
-1 --> -1,000
80 --> 80,000
```

Comment: `9,88` is not a number in Oracle. Do you mean `.` instead of `,` ?

Comment: It's a number, the separator depends on the environment. It could be . o r ,

Comment: Ok, you modified the NLS parameter: `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` -- Cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a format mask with `TO_CHAR` - if you are using `,` as decimal character:

```
TO_CHAR(-1, 'FM999G999G990D000') -> -1,000
TO_CHAR(9.88, 'FM999G999G990D000') -> 9,880
...
```

And make sure your format mask is long enough to fit for all possible length of the numeric string.